# Syntax error while trying to use a macro in QTSPIM simulator

Tags: assembly, macros, qtspim

I am trying to run a simple macro assembly language text in QTSPIM simulator. But I am getting a syntax error , at `.macro` line. I am a beginner in the subject.

```
    .data
    int_str:.asciiz "%d"
    .text
    .macro print_int($arg)
    la $a0, int_str         # Load string address into first arg
    mov $a1, $arg           # Load macro’s parameter ($arg) into second arg
    jal printf              # Call the printf routine
    .end_macro
main:
    print_int($7)
```

I have referred the QTSPIM manual, but they have given the an example exactly like this.

Comment: The manual appears to discuss MIPS assembly in general, not just SPIM specifics. AFAIK SPIM/QtSPIM do not support macros, but MARS does.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It works in MARS

Answer (score 0):

I came across this today.  I said the same thing.

The part where it references Macro's appears to be plagiarized (or with permission- copied from at least) the book Computer Organization and Design.  The next section gives it away. I think the respective authors are colleagues or something my instructor said.

But after experimenting.  Nope- no macros.

QTSpim does not appear to support Macros at all.  MARS is much better anyway.  Class wants to use qtspim, but the ide in MARS is really helpful.